# Sending apple push notification to multiple users from node.js in one connection

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I've seen node module "node-apn" but I don't see how could I send same notification to multiple users in one connection? I've also seen that it is possible to do in PHP but I am using node.js

Answer (score 12):

With node-apn v1.3.x (a highly recommended upgrade) you can send an identical notification to many devices without needing the loop at all. The module will automatically take care of the intricacies around sending one notification to multiple devices for you.

```
// Instantiate a new message
// and set message defaults
var note = new apns.Notification();
note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
note.badge = 3;
note.sound = "ping.aiff";
note.alert = "You have a new message";
note.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Caroline'};

// List of user tokens
var userTokens = ['token1', 'token2', 'token3'];
// Send the message
apnsConnection.pushNotification(note, userTokens);
```

Comment: Very nice and thanks for reply :) ... just another question: how many tokens can I put in array? ... is there any limit?

Comment: There should be no limit, if you have any problems let me know.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the heads up argon. Now I see how that could be a small problem. I'll delete my answer if you'd like to modify yours.

Comment: That's really fabulous. Thanks!